# TextBlock StringFormat Trim Zeros

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, string-formatting

I have an WPF Project with a TextBlock with and a Binding to a number
like `"0009012"` but I want to only show `9012` or for `0881012`
if have to show `881012`.

Is there a way with StringFormat or do I have to write a Converter 
for that?

Here my code:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" StringFormat={}{????}/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string Test { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Test = "00090012";

            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"00090012"` isn't a number. it is a string. it is displayed as is.

Comment: Could you try `StringFormat={}{0:0}}"` and see what's displayed?

Comment: *"Is there a way with StringFormat or do I have to write a Converter for that?"* You have to write a converter.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way with `StringFormat` or do I have to write a `Converter` for that?

The latter.

There is no `StringFormat` you can apply in XAML that removes all leading zeros from a number. Also note that a `StringFormat` is not applied to `string` values.

You could write a converter that for example calls `TrimStart("0")` on the `string` or simply return an already trimmed value from the source property of the view model that you bind to.

Answer (score -1):

```
Test = Convert.ToInt32(Test).ToString();
```

Converting to integer will remove all the initial `0s` and then you can convert it back to string with the `ToString` method.

Comment: i have to do it in WPF/XAML sorry I did not make it clear. Because it´s an PrintLayout wich is loaded in Runtime

Answer (score -2):

int integer = int.Parse(String.ToString()); 
Try this method